# How to pass a Type as an attribute parameter using F# syntax?

Tags: types, f#, nunit, custom-attributes, fscheck

FsCheck allows a custom `Arbitrary` in its NUnit integration:

```
[<Property(Verbose = true, Arbitrary= [typeof<Test.Arithmetic.MyArb>])>]
static member  MultiplyIdentity (x: int64) = x * 1 = x
```

This syntax doesn't work. I feel a bit embarrassed to ask, but apparently I never needed this before: how do you specify the type in F# as an attribute parameter? Microsoft [says nothing about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/attributes), nor does the [Wikibooks project](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Reflection) and I have some trouble googling this (the word *type* is omnipresent).

Note 1: the `Arbitrary` parameter is of type `Type []`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're close, but `[1;2;3]` creates a `list<int>`, you want an array literal using `[| 1;2;3 |]`:

```
[<Property(Verbose = true, Arbitrary= [| typeof<Test.Arithmetic.MyArb> |])>]
static member  MultiplyIdentity (x: int64) = x * 1 = x
```

Comment: Yes, I wasn't showing attention to my list-syntax when writing my question. You are correct, of course, but I was actually focusing on getting the `Type`, and copying your syntax still throws with a _"This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value"_ error. Can you repro or does this syntax work for you?

Comment: Works here: https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/tests/FsCheck.Test/Runner.fs#L21

Comment: My bad. The first error was hidden by the tooltip error in F#, and was _"The type 'MyArb' is not defined"_ I had `Tests.Arithmetic.MyArb`, which exists, but apparently when using `typeof`, you cannot use the FQN??? Either way, when I simplified it to `typeof<MyArb>` it "just worked". Fooled by my own foolishness ;).

Comment: Indeed the FQN does not work generally to refer to a type that lives in the same namespace. That's an interesting find. I think that's because the compiler tries to resolve the name from within its own namespace (i.e. it tries `Test.Test.Arithmetic.MyArb`). But then I'd expect that prefixing `global` would work (it doesn't). I have opened an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1957